# Is there a way to check which conditional in an or statement resulted in the code being ran?

Tags: java, if-statement, datepicker, null, conditional-statements

```
            System.out.println("Both are null");
            return;
        }
        else if(startingDate.getValue()==null){
            System.out.println("Start date is null");
            return;
        }else if(endingDate.getValue()==null){
            System.out.println("Ending date is null");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Instead of this I would like to shorten my code down to something like

```
            System.out.println(x + " is null");
        }
```

Where x is the DatePicker that returned null.
Is there any way to do this, or do I already have the shortest method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ternary operator.Please read the given article and I think that you can do it after that.
https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/ternary-operator

Comment: I don't really see in what this answer helps for the given problem

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using a variable.

```java
DatePicker x;

if(something) {
    x = yourFirstValue
} else if (something_else) {
    x = yourSecondValue;
} else {
    x = yourThirdValue;
}

System.out.println(x + " is null");
```

Make sure you have an else statement by the way, otherwise you need to give your string a default value, because it might not get one.

If there is a possibility that all your conditions are false, then do `DatePicker x = null;` instead of just declaring it, and perform a null check before printing your message.